# Black lock screen in ubuntu 14

Tags: lock-screen

In Ubuntu 13 locking the screen would make the screen black. Is is possible to get this behavior in Ubuntu 14?

I liked the old behavior, because I could use it, when I did not want to be distracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the screen remaining on is the issue, you could just turn off the screen. To turn off the scree, you could issue:

```
xset dpms force off
```

on a terminal.

If you want a shortcut for this command, go to **System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom shortcuts** and then give a name of your choice and the command as

```
xset dpms force off
```

and give a unique shortcut key combination, for eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> for locking the screen.

Comment: This turns off the screen, but it does not lock the screen. But I was able to combine this command with `gnome-screensaver-command -l` to get what I wanted. I would prefer to just turn the screen black, as it is faster to wake it up again, but turning it off works fine, too. Thank you.